# How do I unload a DLL module upon a request from the DLL side to unload it?

Tags: c++, winapi, design-patterns, dll

I have a main program and a DLL library. Both codes can be summarized as below.

```
// DLL Module (Start)
class DllModuleClass : public IDllModuleInterFace
{
    public:
        // ...
        void Terminate() override
        {
            // ...
            pMainModuleObject->OnDllModuleObjectTerminated();   // Notify the main program that the DLL can be unloaded now.
            // Error occurs at this point (as soon as OnDllModuleObjectTerminated() returns), because it frees the DLL module and this region does not exist anymore.
        }
        // ...
    private:
        IMainModuleInterFace * pMainModuleObject;
}

IDllModuleInterFace * GetDllModuleClassInstance();
// DLL Module (End)

// Main Module (Start)
class MainModuleClass : public IMainModuleInterFace
{
    public:
        // ...
        void OnDllModuleObjectTerminated() override
        {
            FreeLibrary(hDllModule); // DLL module is freed from memory here.
        }   // Tries to go back to `Terminate()` inside the DLL module, but the DLL module is freed now.
        // ...
    private:
        IDllModuleInterFace * pDllModuleObject;
}
// Main Module (End)
```

In my code, the DLL module calls a function in the main module in order to notify the main module that the DLL can be unloaded. The main module does so, unloads the DLL from the memory. But the caller from the DLL hasn't return yet. So, after unloading the DLL, there is still a function in the DLL which is still running. This causes an obvious and inevitable runtime error.

Can you suggest a proper way of unloading the DLL in this structure?

Comment: The DLL shouldn't be the monitor; the main application should. Even then timing becomes an issue. One need look no further than the various gyrations MS went through when attempting to get the DllCanUnloadNow nuances to semi-reliably work (especially with ATL) in the in-proc COM architecture to see this is not a trivial problem to solve.

Comment: presumably you'll need to notify the application that the dll should be unloaded then the application will asynchronously on a separate thread wait for nobody to be using the dll (using mutexes?) then unload.

Answer (score 2):

There's a function exactly for this purpose: `FreeLibraryAndExitThread`.

Comment: Mandatory reading: [What is the point of FreeLibraryAndExitThread?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131105-00/?p=2733)